# Pick $2$ out of $6$ choices

Tags: probability

[image]

Please correct me if I'm wrong but should it be "$1$ in $30$"?

Since:
$\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{30}$

Please help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

No, order doesn't matter in this case, since choosing $A$ and $B$ is the same as choosing $B$ and $A$.

This means you have to multiply by $2! = 2$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!